# Deployment pipeline with production react build

Tags: reactjs, docker, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I have a react build and a server build (mongo)
e.g

```
- root
  - server
   -build
   DockerFile
  -client
   -build
  DockerFile
docker-compose.yml
```

This uses github actions on push to build and deploy to an AWS instance

The server is running fine on prod on a seperate port however I'm missing something to be able to run my client on this host. I dont want to serve all my static assets through my express api if I can help it.

Docker compose file:

```js
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: spacer_app_client
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: spacer_app_server
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules # Inside the container, don't try to override this folder, just leave as is
      - ./server:/usr/src/app # Look at the server directory and copy everything into the app folder in the container
```

Comment: Sorry but as this we don't really get what you try to achieve. What does 'run my client on this host" means ? Also I don't get the point with the static assets issue ? if you need a third container with a web server nginx/apache just add it to your compose file.

Comment: sorry I wasn't explaning myseld very well. I think that's it, I need an nginx server within my docker file to be able to host the static files but am not sure the commands/ how to do that

Comment: Well can you show your docker-compose.yml ? This is where you put your third container using an nginx container serving some static files...

Comment: of course! thanks for your input. I will add it to the edit in the main question

Answer (score 1):

You can add an nginx (or what ever other webserver you want to your docker compose:

First go to dockerhub (https://hub.docker.com/), then search "nginx" or whatever you look name is named. Look for an official image. you'll get something like: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

In the documentation page they explain how to run an official nginx server instance with docker by command line like:

```
docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx
```

Ideally you fix the version to have predictive behavior. The doc provide you with the available one. Let get the latest stable one:

```
docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx:1.19.1
```

They explain how to do that with docker-compose too with an example:

```
web:
  image: nginx:1.19.1
  volumes:
   - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  environment:
   - NGINX_HOST=foobar.com
   - NGINX_PORT=80
```

Of course you would adapt the volume, port and alike to your liking.

**Remark:** there thousand of available containers on dockerhub for most database, operating systems, server, build toolchain and alike. So you can run directly python or java app or a web server or whatever that you like with a bit ofconfig.

Comment: This is great, thanks. i'm going to try this out now. One quick question, i presume that I can do all this in a docker container on my local system? and then providing it all works it will work reliably the same on my AWS host?

Comment: Of course everything can be run locally or on whatever env you want. Still it you want your container to work reliably into production, they should not bind to local volumes because in production, the file system will not have such file available on the nodes of your cluster. And that's actually what you do in your docker-compose.yml.... This is nice for testing (instant feedback), not so much for production.

Comment: For production all the files that are actually code (I mean inside your git and part of your commits rather than content dynamically generated by end users) shall be just copied inside the container and part of it. This way they are always available. Use the COPY instruction for that and that mean each new version of your code (a new commit, merge of PR, whatever) will create a new version of yours containers. And deploying the new version of the app is just changing the version of the container in the config file.

Comment: I would also say that you should regularly test using your final target env, like AWS if that's what you use. You can have a test system on top of production and use it for trying and validaiton your configuration incrementally. When it work well on that env, you push it to the production env. But you should really not change the way things are done between dev & prod. If you don't use the same tooling and don't try to deploy using the same tools as in prod when you test, you'll have long integration times and risk to load something in prod that doesn't work and get long downtimes.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I have a fair bit to understand with docker. However you mentioned earlier that " This is nice for testing (instant feedback), not so much for production." However I thought I would be using the same docker-compose file for production as well as local?

Comment: Please check this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/ "Important: Bind mounts can be useful but they can also cause problems. In most cases, it is recommended that you architect your application such that mounting paths from the host is unnecessary"

Comment: It is quite useful to have mount with the local file system for having instant sync when you develop locally. Quite handy. Chances are seen instantly. The same for sharing other resources. But in prod, you typically don't have the file available directly on every node of the cluster and so the bind will not work well in most cases. if you have volumes in prod, you need to manage them and that's a complex task that is best for things like a database.

Comment: Typically I would architect things so that: the container themselve are prod-ready and the same are used in test & prod. For the docker-compose, honestly I would consider having 2 files, 1 for production that also be used for test systems and one for local dev. I do not expect a docker-compose.yml to be that big anyway. Another solution is to have several compose file & merge them, but I am not a big fan (https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/). Anyway for production I'll seriously consider using kubernetes rather than docker-compose. Kubernetes is the de-facto standard for prod.